# Postgres TypeORM - FK to PK that is also FK to another table - constraint error

Tags: database, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In my NestJS application with postgres db I have these 3 entities: `User`, `Writer`, `Book`
and a class named `UserBaseEntity`.

```
export class UserBaseEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string;

    @OneToOne(() => UserEntity, { primary: true, cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'id'})
    user: UserEntity

@Entity()
export class WriterEntity extends UserBaseEntity implements Writer {

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => BookEntity)
    books: BookEntity[];


@Entity()
export class BookEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => WriterEntity, writer => writer.books)
  @JoinColumn({referencedColumnName: 'id', name: 'writerId'})
  writer?: WriterEntity;

  @Column()
  writeId: string;
```

**Writer extends UserBaseEntity class which makes his Primary key(id) be be a foreign key to `UserEntity` table(id).**

**When I tried to make One To Many relation between Writer and Book I am getting this error**

> QueryFailedError: foreign key constraint "FK_XXX" cannot be implemented

or

> writerId violates not-null constraint

So, there is a problem I guess with Postgres when there is this kind of situation:
book.writerId(FK) -> writer.id(FK) -> user.id

Any idea that maybe can help?

A solution I have found is to move the oneToMany decorator from writer entity to user entity. I hope to find a more elegant and logic suitable way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**My educated guess:** inheritance is the the problem here

---

### What I think happened:

The class `UserBaseEntity` is not `abstract` so it is probably being used more than once. **Why is this problematic?** Well, the definition itself states that  the `user` field is defined with relation to `id` field. When directly used - an inner relation is created (so far so good). But, when used by `WriterEntity` the table is created with primary column `id` (so far so good) and `user` field which makes a relation on this table to its `id` column (here things are getting sideways). So, we define an invalid relation (between `user` field and `id` field for `WriterEntity` table) and also try to create another relation from `BookEntity` to this column as well (this relation has a different type). That breaks consistency and normalization rules so it will fail or produce with wrong DB schema.

### My 2 cents:

When using ORMs solutions, inheritance should be limited to primary keys and common fields. Any other definition in a parent class may result in duplicates (at "best") or invalid relations which will result with errors. In person I think that the problem inheritance solves is very different from what `class` represents in ORMs (e.g. defining a `schema`) and that's why as a rule of thumb - I'm not using inheritance when using ORMs (at all). I believe that creating a parent class and allowing inheritance results in a space that encourage developers to make mistakes as a function of time and prefer to avoid this scenario (you may consider this as an act of `enforcement` without `OOP`)

---

**How should you fix this:** Just remove the `user` field from `UserBaseEntity` or stop using inheritance